# Have problems sharing an Excel Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, file-sharing

I am working on an Excel Book and I want to share it with some people.

All the Sheets are linked to another Excel Files, so I need some help with sharing this Excel without any #REF or ERROR in the cells.

Does anyone knows how to make a Copy of the Excel with only values? So the people will not have the ERRORs...

I appreciate the help!!

Comment: 1. Select all, 2. copy, 3. paste special, values only, 4.save as?

Comment: Data > Queries & Connections > Edit Links > Break Link

Comment: Break all links in Excel.